# More convention examples

Tags: regex, brunch

I've been trying to get my head around the Brunch conventions configuration – my lack of comprehension is more than likely due to my lack of experience/knowledge in the world of regex.

It would be great to see an example of how to change the default build location of specific files in the `assets/` folder.

### A use case

I want to move *only* the HTML pages to a folder that *isn't* the public folder. Here's my current folder setup:

```
app
  assets
    _inc
      header.html
      footer.html
      ...
    _layouts
      main.html
      404.html
      ...
  styles
    main.scss
    ..
node_modules
public
craft
  templates
```

In this case I'd like to move all the HTML files: `assets/**/*.html` (in glob parlance) to the `craft/templates` folder.

Any advice, tips, etc would be excellent!

Please & thank you!

Comment: You can match all the html files under assets with `/^assets.*\.html$/`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you just need to loop through all files in your current folder, use a regex like `assets\/.*\/*\.html` to search for a match. If match is found, then move to the folder of your choice (i.e, `craft/templates`).

Here is the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/bI0aX5/1)